# Libre office calc and excel showing different value

Tags: python, excel, csv, data-cleaning, libreoffice-calc

I am trying to do some date parsing in python and while parsing I came to this weird error that said

```
time data 'nan' does not match format '%d/%m/%y'
```

As i checked my *.csv* file in libreoffice calc everything looked fine. No *nan* values what so ever. However when I checked it in excel(excel mobile version. Since I don't want to pay) I saw different value. Value that was shown as follows in different editor

Libre office calc - `11/09/93`

excel - `########`.

Here is a screenshot below:
[image]

How could I change it in LibreOffice or python so that it won't be treated as nan values but the real values like they should be.

I don't have much knowledge in excel and Libreoffice calc so any explanation to solve this simple issue would be welcome.

Here is the python code

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime as dt

loc = "C:/Data/"
season1993_94 = pd.read_csv(loc + '1993-94.csv')

def parse_date_type1(date):
    if date == '':
        return None
    return dt.strptime(date, '%d/%m/%y').date()

def parse_date_type2(date):
    if date == '':
        return None
    return dt.strptime(date, '%d/%m/%Y').date()

season1993_94.Date = season1993_94.Date.astype(str).apply(parse_date_type1)
```

Error:

```
<ipython-input-13-46ff7e1afe94> in <module>()
----> 1 season1993_94.Date = season1993_94.Date.astype(str).apply(parse_date_type1)

ValueError: time data 'nan' does not match format '%d/%m/%y'
```

PS: If the question seems inappropriate as per the context given, please feel free to edit it.

Comment: Enlarge the width of column B

Comment: @MichaelO. I have uploaded new picture.  I cannot allow change width of column B in excel. It doesn't let me change any thing since it is mobile version. However on top in in fx field you can see the value of highlighted cell

Comment: This `#######` is because the value doesn't fit in the cell. As for Python, maybe posting some code will be helpful.

Comment: @MichaelO. added python code

Comment: Well, maybe you have some symbols in the cells so it's not a empty string. Try to print `Date` column without applying the function.

Comment: @MichaelO. Turns out I have  463 rows with values however in python when I try to view date column I see that there are 551 rows. And all the values after row 463 are nan values. Little weird. Any suggestions?

Comment: Check your csv file by opening it in editor, maybe there are some incorrect strings

Comment: I mean first 463 rows have values after that all rows are empty. I tried pandas dropna but didn't work

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show Rows **67,68,69** from your **CSV** File.

Answer (score 0):

To see what is going on, use a text editor such as Notepad++.  Viewing with Excel or Calc may not show the problem; at least, the problem cannot be seen from the images in the question.

The error occurs with a CSV file consisting of the following three lines.

```
Date,Place
28/08/93,Southampton
,Newcastle
```

Here is the solution, adapted from [How to convert string to datetime with nulls - python, pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29298577/how-to-convert-string-to-datetime-with-nulls-python-pandas)

```
season1993_94['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(season1993_94['Date'], errors='coerce')
```

The result:

```
>>> season1993_94
        Date        Place
0 1993-08-28  Southampton
1        NaT    Newcastle
```