# How to create the datetime object equivalent of numpy.nan without using Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, datetime, nan

Given a numpy array of numerical data, one can retrieve the indices of the array that match a particular condition. By accepting `np.nan` as `type <float>`, these conditions can still be met. I would like to use a similar method using datetime objects instead of numerical data.

As an example, consider the following:

```
import numpy as np
import datetime

# sample data
x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 11).astype(int)
y = x**2
z = y.copy().astype(float)
z[0] = np.nan

# check that nan condition is correctly satisfied
print("\nZ:\n{}\n".format(z))
print("\nZ > 0:\n{}\n".format(z > 0))
print("\nZ < 0:\n{}\n".format(z < 0))
print("\nZ = 0:\n{}\n".format(z == 0))

# get number of elapsed hours between two datetime objects
dt0 = datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 11, 23, 59, 59)
dt1 = datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 12, 23, 59, 59)
hr_delta = (dt1 - dt0).total_seconds() // 3600
print("\n{} - {} = {} hours".format(dt1, dt0, hr_delta))
```

Since `np.nan - 5 = np.nan`, it would be very convenient for me to use this idea to create an invalid datetime object. However, datetime objects require the inputs of type `<int>`, whereas `np.nan` is `type <float>`. The example below recreates the source of my problem:

```
# attempt to instantiate invalid datetime object
dt2 = datetime.datetime(np.nan, 1, 11, 23, 59, 59)
```

which throws `TypeError: integer argument expected, got float`. Is there a way to do this without using pandas, as suggested in this [alternate post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29298577/how-to-convert-string-to-datetime-with-nulls-python-pandas)? Just to clarify, my goal is to create an invalid datetime object such that its subtraction or addition with a valid datetime object returns a nan-like value.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Anything pandas does is usually something Numpy does.

In this instance, you need to store the proper type, which is not `datetime`, but `np.datetime64`. Once you have this type, you can fill `NaT` values with `np.datetime64("NaT")` and then use `np.isnat` to test if a value if a time or not.

`datetime` itself doesn't provide a concept of "not a time", you have to use a type that does. You should be able to use `np.datetime64` in a close fashion as a `datetime`.