# pd.to_datetime - what to fill missing values with

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of 70 columns and 200,000 records. There are 6 date fields in dmy format that I would like to change to pd.datetime format. 
The date columns are 
`["ADMIDATE", "DISDATE", "EPIEND", "EPISTART", "OPDATE_01", "DOD"]`
I am using the following code to change them to datetime.

```
for col in [["ADMIDATE", "DISDATE", "EPIEND", "EPISTART", "OPDATE_01", "DOD"]]:
    df1[col] = pd.to_datetime(df1[col], format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

I am getting an error

```
ValueError: to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be specified: [day,month,year] is missing
```

Looking for the number of null values I find % missing

DISDATE - 4.0%,
OPDATE_01 - 14.0%,
DOD - 82.0%

The other date columns have no missing values.
I wondered about using .fillna(0) but that would not satisfy pd.to_datetime. 
What to do to force conversion of the fields that have date entries ?, I can't delete them.

Comment: Does this post help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29298577/how-to-convert-string-to-datetime-with-nulls-python-pandas It explains how to deal with missing values. If appropriate you could try to interpolate those missing values using the values on each side of the missing ones.

Comment: tried ```errors='coerce'``` with no joy. I can't really interpolate as the fields that have entries will contribute to  calculation and the fields that don't must remain blank.

Comment: try df1[col] = pd.to_datetime(df1[col], **dayfirst=True**) If you specify a format you have to make sure that all entries satisfy this format. dayfirst=True is a less strict parameter.

Comment: Unfortunately same error. Might require a rethink in my design.