# How to convert a Unix Timestamp of a Pandas DataFrame Column with NaN Values to a Datetime

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a Unix timestamp column and some `NaN` values, like that:

```
>> df_to_datetime

0    1.571687e+09
1    1.586099e+09
2             NaN
3    1.589994e+09
4    1.593363e+09
5    1.585852e+09
6    1.580754e+09
7    1.582201e+09
8    1.576595e+09
9    1.586874e+09
Name: last_replied_at, dtype: float64
```

When I try that:

```
for i in range (len(df_to_datetime)):
  if not df_to_datetime[i]:
    pass
  else:
    df_to_datetime[i] = [datetime.utcfromtimestamp(df_to_datetime[i]).astimezone(time_zone)]
    print(df_to_datetime[i])
```

it returns this:

```
     11     pass
     12   else:
---> 13     df_to_datetime[i] = [datetime.utcfromtimestamp(df_to_datetime[i]).astimezone(time_zone)]
     14     print(df_to_datetime[i])
     15 

ValueError: Invalid value NaN (not a number)
```

I want to convert my Unix timestamp columns to a datetime. I tried to do without `if/else` before, but got the same problem with `NaN` values...

Comment: What datetime would you want the NaNs to translate to?

Comment: Just NaN, I want to ignore NaN when convert

Comment: NaN is a valid datetime?

Comment: In case your first if statement is to catch NaN, you should use the pandas function `if pd.isnull(pandas_cell) == False:`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert string to datetime with nulls - python, pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29298577/how-to-convert-string-to-datetime-with-nulls-python-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

```
df_to_datetime[i] = [datetime.utcfromtimestamp(df_to_datetime[i]).astimezone(time_zone), errors='coerce']
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this in a loop and with if/else, checkout the [apply method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html), with setup:

```
>> df_to_datetime = pd.Series(pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='1/08/2018'), 
                          name='last_replied_at').apply(pd.Timestamp.timestamp)
>> df_to_datetime.iloc[2] = np.nan
>> print(df_to_datetime)

0    1.514765e+09
1    1.514851e+09
2             NaN
3    1.515024e+09
4    1.515110e+09
5    1.515197e+09
6    1.515283e+09
7    1.515370e+09
Name: last_replied_at, dtype: float64

>> df_to_datetime.apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='coerce', utc=True, unit='s')

0   2018-01-01 00:00:00+00:00
1   2018-01-02 00:00:00+00:00
2                         NaT
3   2018-01-04 00:00:00+00:00
4   2018-01-05 00:00:00+00:00
5   2018-01-06 00:00:00+00:00
6   2018-01-07 00:00:00+00:00
7   2018-01-08 00:00:00+00:00
Name: last_replied_at, dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]
```